# Change definition of "under the cursor" for ctags with C++ qualifiers

Tags: ctags, custom-text-object

When jumping to a tag it seems that ":" are ignored for the purpose of "under the cursor" (I'm assuming it's "word" "under the cursor"). For example if I want to jump to

```
myTree::Node something
```

I want proper Node definition to be identified (I did run ctags with +q), rather than the plethora of system library nodes I have tagged.

I thought I worked around this using

```
vnoremap ak <ESC>?[^a-zA-Z0-9:_]<CR>lv/[^a-zA-Z0-9:_]<CR>h
```

so I could easily mark the full qualifier when I'm on top of it, then `ctrl-]` and `g]` work nicely.

Unfortunately it seems the `ctrl-w` commands ignore the mark, and still use only "Node" in the above example for the matching.

I want `<ctrl-w> <ctrl-]>` to work as expected when the full qualifier is marked. Even better, I would like to change the definition of "under the cursor" or "word", or the used text object to include ":" (this will probably only annoy in Python anyway) so I won't even need my mapping. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Comment: You might could adjust `iskeyword`, but that has far-reaching effects

Comment: @D.BenKnoble After reading a bit, I'm trying to avoid that for now, but you might add that as an answer anyway, in case that's the only solution. Perhaps somehow wrap it in a command that rebinds it and then rebinds it back or the like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I remapped `<C-w><C-]>`. I am still looking for other, more "holistic" solutions. Added these lines to my .vimrc:

```
noremap <C-w><C-]> :split<bar>normal vak<CR>g<C-]>
noremap <C-w>] :normal vak<CR>g<C-]>
```

which conveniently mark said custom text object, and jumps to it if there is a single definition, or opens a list of matches otherwise. The two variants either split the window or jump in the same one.